# How to use if-else condition in Scala's Filter?

Tags: scala

I have an ArrayBuffer with data in the following format: period_name:character varying(15) year:bigint. The data in it represents column name of a table and its datatype. My requirement is to extract the column name period and the datatype, just character varying excluding substring from "(" till ")" and then send all the elements to a ListBuffer. I came up with the following logic:

```
for(i <- receivedGpData) {
   gpTypes = i.split("\\:")
   if(gpTypes(1).contains("(")) {
       gpColType = gpTypes(1).substring(0, gpTypes(1).indexOf("("))
       prepList += gpTypes(0) + " " + gpColType
   } else {
       prepList += gpTypes(0) + " " + gpTypes(1)
   }
}
```

The above code is working but I am trying to implement the same using Scala's Map and Filter functions. What I don't understand is how to use the if-else condition in the Scala Filter after the condition:

```
var reList = receivedGpData.map(element => element.split(":"))
                           .filter{ x => x(1).contains("(")
                                  }
```

Could anyone let me know how can I implement the same code in for-loop using Scala's map & filter functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val receivedGpData = Array("bla:bla(1)","bla2:cat")

val res = receivedGpData
  .map(_.split(":"))
  .map(s=>(s(0),s(1).takeWhile(_!='(')))
  .map(s => s"${s._1} ${s._2}").toList

println(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
val p = "(\\w+):([.[^(]]*)(\\(.*\\))?".r
val res = data.map{case p(x,y,_)=>x+" "+y}
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val data = Array("period_name:character varying(15)","year:bigint")
data: Array[String] = Array(period_name:character varying(15), year:bigint)
scala> val p = "(\\w+):([.[^(]]*)(\\(.*\\))?".r
p: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w+):([.[^(]]*)(\(.*\))?
scala> val res = data.map{case p(x,y,_)=>x+" "+y}
res: Array[String] = Array(period_name character varying, year bigint)
```